# Split string with numbers

Tags: javascript, parsing

I've been trying to split a string by numbers. Basically I have a string such as:

```
"10x + 10"
```

JS splits it and gets:

```
["+10x", "+10"]
```

I've tried doing this a few times but haven't hit success. If I understand it right I just need to split it by `+ - / *`. My best attempt was this:

```
var statement = ["10x + 10"]
var spliters = ['+', '-', '*', '/'];

for (i = 0; i < spliters.length; i++) {
    for (o = 0; o < statement.length; o++) {
        statement[o] = statment[o].split(spliters[i]);
        for (p = 0; p < statment[o].length - 1; p++) {
            statement[o][p] = spliters[i] + statement[o][p];
        }
        statement = flatten(statement);
    }
}
```

But it doesn't work. Also I only want `+` and `-` to be in front on the array elements and not `*` and `/`. If anyone could help me with this is would be much appreciated.

Comment: What does the *correct* output look like? Are you trying to tokenize your string so that you have numbers and operators?

Comment: The second array (`["+10x", "+10"])

Comment: "But it doesn't work" What happens when you run this code? And how does it differ from what you want?

Comment: It runs through if I put just one character `6` but as soon as I put `+ - *` or `/` it messes up the script and says `function not defined` when I run it again

Comment: I also suggest you research different parsing techniques. If you want to parse an arbitrary mathematical expression (or even just a polynomial), you will need to use more sophisticated techniques.

Comment: The "'statment' is not defined" error is because you misspelled statement twice and the compiler is not finding the variable 'statment' as there is only one called 'statement'.

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that `Array.prototype.split()` can take a regular expressions:

```
let str = "10x + 10";
let arr = str.split(/[+|-|\*|/]/);
console.log(arr); // output: ["10x ", " 10"];
```

This is not a good way to parse arithmetical expressions, though. To do that, I recommend the [Shunting-yard algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting-yard_algorithm).

Comment: Thanks but this doesn't keep the symbol